# Phpseclib inside wordpress is not working

Tags: php, wordpress, ssh, phpseclib

I installed phpseclib in my wordpress site. Every time I run the this script, it shows blank page and even it hides wordpress admin bar.

```
include('Net/SSH2.php');
$ssh = new Net_SSH2('www.domain.tld');

if (!$ssh->login('username', 'password')) 
{
    exit('Login Failed');
}
echo $ssh->exec('pwd');

echo $ssh->exec('ls -la');`
```

But then I placed the library outside the wordpress and it works perfectly. What could be the problem? I really need the code running inside the wordpress.Thanks in advance!

Comment: This is how I am including the library: set_include_path(get_include_path() . get_include_path().'/phpseclib');
include('Net/SSH2.php');

Comment: You don't need to do get_include_path() twice ;)

Comment: Sorry. That was a typo. I included only one time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess: phpseclib isn't in the in the include_path in your script. The blank page that you're getting is probably due to a Fatal error stemming from PHP being unable to instantiate the Net_SSH2 class because Net/SSH2.php wasn't included.

If you set `display_errors = 1` and `error_reporting = E_ALL` you'd probably see the error.

Comment: I am getting this error message: Failed opening 'Net/SSH2.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/share/pear.:/usr/lib64/php:/usr/share/pear/phpseclib')

Comment: Did you install phpseclib via PEAR? What does it look like if you do /usr/share/pear/phpseclib?

Comment: First of all, thank you for answering my questions. I did install via PEAR. Followed instruction on http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/pear.htm   I changed my directory to /usr/share/pear then i installed. Was I supposed to create new directory called 'phpseclib'? I thought it will create it for me. When I do /usr/share/pear/phpseclib , it says no such file or directory exists.

Comment: In which directory should I be in when i install phpseclib?

Comment: The directory you installed it in should be fine. I suggested what I did because I'm not too familiar with phpseclib's PEAR channel but thought it might follow the structure of phpseclib on github.com. I guess it doesn't. In lieu of that my best guess is that your Wordpress install is running as a different user - a user who doesn't have permission to access /usr/share/pear or whatever - than the other script you ran that worked. If that's the case you could do chmod -r on the directory, maybe do phpsuexec to change the user running apache, etc.

Comment: I did chmod -r g+rwx /usr/share/pear. And it keep saying 'Read only file system'. And it is not changing permission. I am using putty.Now permission is  drwxr-xr-x. I also did chmod -r go+rwx /usr/share/pear. It all saying changing permission then: Read -only file system.

Comment: I did mount -o remount. But it keep saying "only root can do that". What should I do? How to log in as a "root"? (Mine is putty running on windows)

Comment: Try `sudo mount -o remount`

Comment: It said : sudo: unable to stat /etc/sudoers: No such file or directory
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin

Comment: And i was trying something like this: mount -o remount,uid=anna1 /usr/share/pear . Then it changed from root to anna1. But permission is drwx--x--- 28 anna1 nobody 4096. How to change user permission here?

Comment: Can you do the chmod now?

Comment: Maybe make another stackoverflow topic about chmod not letting you make changes? idk :(

Comment: Ok thanks for helping me out. I really appreciate your consistent responses.